# import class from different python package

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, import, package

I checked lots of questions on SO, but couldn't solve it.
I have a python structure like :

```
test_env/
    |A/
    |  |__init__.py
    |  |lib/
    |      |abc.py
    |      |__init__.py
    |lib/
    |  |file1.py    #this has a class MyClass
    |  |__init__.py
    |test/
    |  |test.py   #executing this file
```

My PYTHONPATH:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/username/test_env/A/lib/:/Users/username/test_env/lib"
```

test_env/test/test.py

```
from abc import some_function
from lib.file1 import MyClass

-----
```

which gives error: `ImportError: No module named abc`
and `No module named lib.file1`

Note: I am using pyCharm, which is able to find above modules when i type `from abc import some_function`.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is a typo, but your file structure is '/Users/username/test_env/A/lib/' not '/Users/username/test/A/lib/'

If it didn't solve the issue, you can try this in the beginning of your test_env/test/test.py fie:

```
sys.path.append('/Users/username/test_env/A/lib/')
sys.path.append('/Users/username/test_env/lib/')
from abc import some_function
from file1 import MyClass
```

It explicitly adds a string to your PATH variable just for the script your are dealing with.